# Use Mixin in template with Nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to call the mixin function within the template. Vue documentation says mixin and the component are merged but i can't call the function.

> *getImage is not a function*

**Mixin**

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      l: 2,
      output: 'webp'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    getImage() {
      return 'www.example.url'
    }
  }
}
```

**Component**

```
<template>
  <v-img :src="getImage()" />
</template>

<script>
import imageMixin from '~/mixins/image'

export default {
  name: 'New',
  mixin: { imageMixin }
}
</script>

<style scoped></style>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Change `mixin: { imageMixin }` to `mixins: [imageMixin]`

Comment: Thanks. Bad mistake.